# Responsive web-site - Only Android immediately starts to Continuous Zooming In On Load

Tags: android, html, responsive-design, media-queries

I have not found any similiar issues searching the issue.

Website: http://davidbrownhydraulics.com (old design, not mine)

Works fine in: iPhone 4/5/iPad/etc

Does not work in: Android phones... Galaxy S2 and other Galaxy's. (need to actually load it on an Android phone and see how it works)

What I get when testing this website is the responsive view that SHOULD be there shows up first, but then it very quickly just keeps expanding. Its as if the browser is deciding to zoom in forever, continuously. I have tried to pin point where it may be causing that problem, it should be snapping to the max-device-width or maybe I could just target android phones in one go somehow?

**Anyone have any ideas I could try out?** I have tried a lot of different META content type things, changing the break points (i have a feeling it may be off for the galaxy s2? or the android has a different pixel-scale) to no avail.

Here are the relevant sections of coding:

Head Meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" name="viewport" content="charset=UTF-8, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
```

Media Query:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width:767px)
```

My CSS to it: (idea that it will just snap to the max device width)

```
html { width:100%; overflow-x:hidden; }
body { width:100%; overflow-x:hidden; }
#outer { width:100%; }
#main { width:100%; }
#header { width:100%; max-width:100%; overflow:hidden; }
```

Thanks in advance, appreciate it if anyone gives it a go to load on their Android phone and let me know their thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Setting a viewport tells the browser how content should fit on the device's screen and informs the browser that the site is optimized for mobile (Android, Windows, iOS).tells the browser to set the viewport to the width of the device with an initial scale of 1.

Try this.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
```

This will work perfectly on all view-ports.

Comment: A few stressful hours later of trying to figure why, I realised it was this that is needed for Android to pick it up in the CSS:

"media screen" will not pick up the view point. I changed it to     "media **all**" and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

A few stressful hours later of trying to figure why, I realised it was this that is needed for Android to pick it up in the CSS:

```
@media screen
```

will not pick up the view point. I changed it to

```
@media all
```

and works fine :) gah! the simple things...

Answer (score 0):

Well, another look into it all, I have adjusted my CSS media queries (see source if need be) but this main bit of coding has helped. Looks like trying to set a 100% width on everything was making something blow up, causing android to go wierd.

Putting this under my css break point (and modifying it for ur own needs, if this helps someone) has helped and kept the website browsable now. A good quick fix.

```
html { width:100%; overflow-x:hidden; max-width:480px !important; }
body { width:100%; overflow-x:hidden; max-width:480px!important; }
img { max-width:480px !important;}
```